# how can i traverse to specific child A by locating child B of same Parent?

Tags: java, xpath, appium, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I am trying to traverse to three dots button (overflow_menu) via locating "Premium" tag on Parent element.

Additional info:
1. I am trying for Appium using Java.

My aim:
Child B--> Same Parent --> action on Child A

I have tried few x-paths but nothing is working for me.

I would appreciate help for the same. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks.

[image: It's Child A info]

[image: It's Parent Element info]

[image: It's Child B info]

Comment: try using **appium desktop inspector** to inspect the elements. it will provide you with unique xpath or automationId( if any present)

Comment: I am able to find that element independent. But my requirement is to click on "Overflow_menu" only on those movies which are labelled as "Premium.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the xpath that will get all the premium movies "Overflow_menu".

```
//*[@class='android.widget.TextView' and .='Premium']/parent::*/*[@class='android.widget.ImageView']
```